# How to count idle time only for one component in the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to use "react-idle-timer" for calculating idle time on a component. I don't want to count the idle time for the whole page, instead I want to count the idle time only for one component on the page( in my case I build a chatbot. So I want to count the time that I'm not using the chatbot while doing some other things on the page). Please help me... If you can give me any solution (even in vanilla Js) I will appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this article. with idle timer package.

```
npm i react-idle-timer --save
```

wrap with the component below

```
<IdleTimer
            ref={ref => { this.idleTimer = ref }}
            element={document}
            onActive={this.onActive}
            onIdle={this.onIdle}
            onAction={this.onAction}
            debounce={250}
            timeout={this.state.timeout} /> </IdleTimer>
```

refer :
https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-implement-idle-timeout-in-react-830d21c32942

Comment: Slightly out of date. I've added an update.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed in the latest version of IdleTimer. To use IdleTimer in the above way, IdleTimer must now be declared as:

```js
import { Component } from 'react'
import { withIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'

class IdleTimerComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

export const IdleTimer = withIdleTimer(IdleTimerComponent)
```

More at https://idletimer.dev/docs/getting-started/new#breaking-changes